# Resolve public GitHub Action in nested directory

Tags: javascript, github-actions

I've been following the GitHub Action guide for [creating a javascript action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action) and would like to use Lerna to better manage multiple actions in a single repo. I have therefore moved the actions into a `packages` folder which I find to be quite tidy.

When [using the action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action#example-using-a-public-action), I need to alter the code from something like:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Hello world action step
    id: hello
    uses: octocat/example-repo/awesome-action@v1.1
```

to

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Hello world action step
    id: hello
    uses: octocat/example-repo/packages/awesome-action@v1.1
```

I've been trying to workout if it is possible to maintain the directory structure (all actions stored in `packages`) without needing to include `packages` path in the workflow or if I need to move them out into the root directory. I've tried a few things like adding `exports` to my root package.json file, but I always get the error:

```js
Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under
```

Comment: From what I can tell, this looks correct. Have you verified if directory (and action.yml therein) exists in the tag `v1.1` ?